# Why is FtpWebRequest corrupting text that's appended to a file?

Tags: c#, networking, ftp, upload, corrupt

I'm trying to use FTP to add lines of text to a .txt file stored on a web server. It's connecting and appending the text, but for some reason it's corrupted and displays as random characters (symbols, Chinese etc). Here is my code:

```
byte[] data = md5Encryptor.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString));

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpAddress + "file.txt");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile;
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.Credentials = ftpCredentials;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

To try to debug, I converted 'data' from a byte[] back into a string using this code:

```
public static string BytesToString(byte[] data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(data[i].ToString("X2"));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Here's what the above method returned, an md5 hash string as expected:

```
E904B52B435BF0E1DA8D4CE6EC47E45A
```

This is what the same 'data' var, appended to my file via FTP, ended up as:

```
ө⮵孃跚䟬嫤
```

I've even tried this, just in case there was an encoding issue:

```
string dataString = BytesToString(data);
bytes[] newBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
```

Didn't work. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try encoding the data in bytes refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string/

Comment: Is the file in the FTP server saved as `ASCII`?

Comment: Ascii file can hardly contain `04`. What encoding does the file use?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the .txt was encoded as Unicode not ASCII. Wikipedia said ASCII was the default, but if you open the 'Save As' menu you can check. As soon as I saved with Encoding.Unicode it worked fine.